# asp.net mvc 5 need base url for ajax call

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new in ASP.Net.

I want to have URLs like:

```
http://example.com/Controller/Action
```

Right now I am calling URL from script is like this:

```
$('#datatable').dataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [{ 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [-1] }],
    "oLanguage": { "oPaginate": { "sPrevious": "", "sNext": "" } },
    "iDisplayLength": 5,
    "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
    "sDom": 'T<"panel-menu dt-panelmenu"lfr><"clearfix">tip',
    "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "vendor/plugins/datatables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    },
    "sAjaxSource": "admin/Categories",
});
```

Currently using relative URL:

```
"sAjaxSource": "admin/Categories/Index/"
```

The problem with this URL is it is relative URL, but I want to define the base URL before defining the controller and action.

How can I implement this in .cshtml file under `<script>` tag?

If I am doing it the wrong way, then I would be keen to learn the right way to implement the URLs for AJAX calls?

### Update

Sorry, I forgot to mention, I am using MVC Areas, I want to have Base URL for Areas. Admin is defined under Areas directory.

Comment: Its just a `.cshtml` file that you'd create in the `App_Code` folder (right-click on the project->Add->Add ASP.NET Folder->App_Code). You don't have to do anything to use the base url, it tells the browser where to request from. So if you set base url to `/application/site` when requesting `/page.html` it would look at `/application/site/page.html`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to generate your action url is :

```
@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = "AreaName" })
```

Answer (score 2):

What I've found works best is to define your base url in the html in your layout

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <base href="@Functions.GetApplicationPath(Request)" />
    // Other header stuff
</head>
```

And define that @Functions in your `App_Code` folder (might have to create it)

```
@functions {

    public static string GetApplicationPath(HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        // Gets the base url in the following format: "http(s)://domain(:port)/AppPath);
        var applicationPath = request.Url.Scheme + "://" + request.Url.Authority + GetApplicationType(request);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(applicationPath) || !applicationPath.EndsWith("/"))
        {
            applicationPath += "/";
        }

        return applicationPath;
    }

    public static string GetApplicationType(HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        var applicationType = request.ApplicationPath;
        return applicationType;
    }
}
```

This lets you separate out your cshtml and your javascript so you can use relative urls and the base url will handle any website prefixes like `http://yoururl/blah/actualsiteHere`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a script tag within a Razor view, you can use the UrlHelper:

```
'sAjaxSource': '@Url.Action("index", "categories", new { area = "admin" })'
```

Otherwise, you can also make it a root-based URL with:

```
"/admin/Categories"
```

Comment: oh sorry, My bad. Admin is the Area, Categories is the Controller and Index is the Action. I didnt wrote Index because it was going there automatically.
I am using MVC Areas.

Comment: @SizzlingCode As M.Azad shows, it still works, you just have to add the area route value.

Comment: Yes, i copied his code and it was working under areas. Thankyou.

Comment: @SizzlingCode I added an answer that lets you have absolute urls without needing to use javascript in your razor views.

Comment: @John
Thankyou, I am new in ASP.Net and will surely look and will try to understand you answer. Can you please tell what should be the File Name and type under App_Code Directory and do i have to use namespaces? plus how to call baseurl in my views?
If possible please Answer under your Answer.